# AS3 Flash - color picker with eyedropper?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to make a color picker with eyedropper? I have seen in a flash game :/

Comment: well, if you have seen it in a flash game, then there is apparently a way to make a color picker with eyedropper.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ? http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/rgbs/